# PHP - Is there a way to convert an array inside a string to a valid array in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am having a simple problem that I think I need help with.

So, I have an
`<input type="hidden" name="valid_time[]" value="<?php print_r($valid_time); ?>">` tag.

Here, the value of that input is

```
Array ( [Monday] => Array ( [start_time] => 10:00:00 [end_time] => 17:00:00 ) [Tuesday] => Array ( [start_time] => 10:00:00 [end_time] => 17:00:00 ) [Wednesday] => Array ( [start_time] => 10:00:00 [end_time] => 17:00:00 ) [Thursday] => Array ( [start_time] => 10:00:00 [end_time] => 17:00:00 ) )
```

Now, when I submit the form and get the value of that input, I get the result of a string.

`print_r($_POST['valid_time'][0])` => this gives me the value but in a form of a string.

I need the `[0]` because the supposed array is inside the `$_POST['valid_time']` which is also an array.

`print_r(gettype($_POST['valid_time'][0]));` gives me `string`.

What I want is to have that as an array so that I can loop through it. Is there a way in PHP to do that?

PS: If this post is duplicated, pls drop the link and I'll give it a go. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `print_r()` for this. You can use `<?= json_encode($valid_time) ?>` instead and then decode the json with: `$_POST['valid_time'][0] = json_decode($_POST['valid_time'][0]);` to get it as a PHP array again. Another option would be to create multiple hidden input fields, one for each value you want to post.

Comment: Okay, I will try it. If it works, I'll be glad to mark your suggestion as the answer to my problem. So, if you don't mind, you can make your comment as an answer. :) Thank u

Comment: @M.Eriksson, so what I did was to wrap the json_encode() inside an htmlspecialchars() function and it finally worked. Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out.

As for the value inside the input, it should be

```php
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($array)) ?>
```

Now, after POST-ing, you can retrieve it by using:

`json_decode($_POST['array'])`

So, basically, I just forgot to put the `htmlspecialchars()` function.